# How to determine if a text has balanced delimiters?

Tags: java, delimiter

I have this question,

Write a function to determine if a text has balanced delimiters. The pairs of valid delimiters are (), [], {}, and <>. They may be nested. In addition, determine that text delimiters ' and " are properly matched.

I am coding in java by the way..

For each test line, output is "1" if it has balanced delimiters, "0" otherwise.

An example below,

```
4 --- 0

{123} --- 1

{qweqwe{sdad} --- 0
```

The problem, is, how can I write in java code, to check whether the pair of valid delimiters are matched? Sorry, I have very little knowledge of delimiters.

Below is my code..

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a1 = "";
        try {
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("2.in.txt"));
            while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {

                a1 = readFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(a1);
                if (a1.equals("18")) {
                    System.out.println("0");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("1");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/StackExampleDelimiterMatching.htm), it solves a similar task.

```
import java.util.Stack;

class BracketChecker {
  private String input;

  public BracketChecker(String in) {
    input = in;
  }

  public void check() {
    Stack<Character> theStack = new Stack<Character>();

    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
      char ch = input.charAt(j);
      switch (ch) {
      case '{': 
      case '[':
      case '(':
        theStack.push(ch);
        break;
      case '}': 
      case ']':
      case ')':
        if (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
          char chx = theStack.pop();
          if ((ch == '}' && chx != '{') || (ch == ']' && chx != '[') || (ch == ')' && chx != '('))
            System.out.println("Error: " + ch + " at " + j);
        } else

          System.out.println("Error: " + ch + " at " + j);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!theStack.isEmpty()){
      System.out.println("Error: missing right delimiter");
    }
  }
}

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    input = "[]]()()";

    BracketChecker theChecker = new BracketChecker(input);
    theChecker.check();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The general solution for this problem is to use a Stack. For each input string, starting with an empty stack:

- When an open bracket is encountered, push it into the stack.
- When a close bracket is encountered, pop from stack and compare with the close bracket to see whether they are a matching pair. If not, return `false`. If yes, continue.

When you have finished going through the string, check whether the stack is empty. If yes, return `true`, else return `false`.

For the case of quotes `'` and `"`, if you disallow a quote to be inside the same quote, and you don't consider escape syntax, then the solution should be the same.

Comment: Yeah, it helped! but can elaborate more on the these quote ' and ", how to i checked if if those quotes are matched? just like the bracket matching thing..

Comment: @Amazinglykai: Didn't I say that they would be the same (under some assumption)? Otherwise, you would need to carefully define how the escaping should be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean symbolsBalanced(String delimiter){
    String delimiters = "[]{}<>()";
    String text = "{(){}(){()(()())}}";
    Stack<Character> myStack= new Stack<Character>();
    int length = delimiters.length();
    left = new char[length/2];
    right = new char[length/2];
    for (int i=0; i<length/2; i++) {
        left[i] = delimiters.charAt(i+i); //It will contain [,{,<,(
        right[i] = delimiters.charAt(i+i+1); //It will contain ],},>,)
    }

    int tLen = text.length();
    for (int i=0; i<tLen; i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        for(int j=0; j<left.length; j++) {
            if(left[j]==c) {
                //If start braces is present, add in stack
                myStack.add(c);
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0; j<right.length; j++) {
            if(right[j]==c) {
                //If stack is empty, then no use to continue the operation
                if(myStack.isEmpty()) return false;
                //If end braces is present, pop from stack
                myStack.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(myStack.isEmpty()) return true;
    return false;
}
```