# Regex to get everything between spaces or ""

Tags: java, regex

I want to transform strings like this:

```
test1 test2 "test 3" test4 "test 5"
```

Into a list which contains all items between the space characters and the `""`.

By the way: those `"` should not be inside the string

Thats my code:

```
    String test = "test1 test2 \"test 3\" test4 \"test 5\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\".*?\")");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

But this will only match me everything between the `""`. Thats the result:

```
["test 3", "test 5"]
```

How can I modify my regex to match everything between whitespaces AND `""`?

At the end the output should look like this:

```
[test1, test2, test 3, test4, test 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?="\s|"$)|[^\s"]+
```

Additionally, if you plan to use the regular expression very often, it is recommended to use a constant in order to avoid recompile it each time, e.g.:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"\\s|\"$)|[^\\s\"]+");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "test1 test2 \"test 3\" test4 \"test 5\"";

    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test1
test2
test 3
test4
test 5
```

See online [***demo***](http://ideone.com/O7BdDW).

Comment: Will work so +1. I just hope that there will never be input like `"foo bar"baz`.

Comment: Did you mean to validate the input? Somethings like http://stackoverflow.com/a/11610970/870248

Comment: Not quite, problem is not the balance, but that `"` can be reused and to prevent it from being reused your answer relies on fact that closing `"` must either have space after it or be placed at end of input. This means that `"` in `bar"baz` can't be treated as valid closing quote, and as result everywhere `[^\s"]+` will be applied, and instead of `foo bar` `baz` we will see `foo` `bar` `baz`. IMO simpler solution would be not changing only regex, but also algorithm which is using it. So we should allow regex to consume quotes and in algorithm determine if we matched quoted text or not.

Answer (score 1):

Other approach would be simply not changing only regex, but your entire algorithm so you would not to rely only on regex which can have problems with making decision if `"` is end or start of quote. So you could simply try [solution posted earlier by sp00m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31835993/1393766) (now deleted) which used regex

```
"[^"]*"|[^ ]+
```

which would consume `"` characters and later in your code simply check if your match starts with `"` or not. If it does handling removing `"` and if not simply place matched part to list.

So your slightly modified code can look like

```
String test = "test1 test2 \"test 3\" test4 \"test 5\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|[^ ]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String matched = matcher.group();
    if (matched.startsWith("\"")){
        list.add(matcher.group(1));//take only part between quotes
    }else{
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Such solution seems to be cleaner and probably safer in case your input could also be in form of `foo"bar baz"bam` where it is hard for regex to not include `"` as part of match and be able to determine which `"` can and which can't be opening/closing quote.

Comment: For me it is okay if the regex fails with a string like `foo"bar baz"bam`. The list of strings I get from the regex are used as filters. So if the user enters your string, it could either mean "search for `foo AND bar baz AND bam`" or "search for `foo"bar baz"bam"`. Anyway +1 because others may choose your solution if strings like `foo"bar baz"bam ` are valid as input in their case.